# How can I find out the adoption rates of Google Web Fonts?

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-webfonts

I would like to use a common Google Web Font so I added this link to my page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" />
```

How can I find out how likely it is that this font will already be in my browser. Is anyone aware of any published statistics?

Comment: Do you mean you want to know if your visitors have it installed in their OS, or have it cached in their browser?

Comment: It's the Open Sans font so I don't think most will have it installed in the OS. I would like to know about browser cache stats.

Comment: Browse cache stats is not useful, because one can never predict the frequency of users clearing their caches and etc. I'm quite sure Google fonts are cached in the browser.

Comment: And if you knew the answer; if you found that, say, 0.2% of all computers worldwide had Open Sans cached, what would you do with this information?

Comment: I would probabloy not use OpenSans web font at least for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some stats for the font here (statistics tab):

http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans

Incidentally, I can't actually figure out how to get to that from the Google font page itself, so just change the URL to find the stats for other fonts.

It shows how many times the font has been requested from Google's servers, but I highly doubt any stats exist for what fonts people have cached, nor would anybody go to the effort of trying to establish that. People's caches change all the time.

You are possibly worrying too much about the caching of the font. It's a tiny asset to load once if not already cached.